# 301 Redirect just first Subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a 301 Redirect from one page to another

```
REDIRECT 301 /cloud-computing /it-infrastructure/cloud-computing
```

Now when i use this redirect also the subpages of cloud-computing are affected by this 301 redirect, but they have to be redirected somewhere else. How can i just redirect the folder and not the subpages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `RedirectMatch` for precise matching using regex:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/cloud-computing/?$ /it-infrastructure/cloud-computing
```

Clear your browser cache before testing the change.